# Mapping an array of objects seems not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm working with a library called React Three Fiber as it helps render 3D models. I'm trying to do a solar system so I need the moons to be grouped in the same group as the planets. When I get the data from the API console.log works correctly, but when I map the planets console.log doesn't work. I simplied the code taking out most three fiber things as I think it might be a javascript issue. The only thing from Three Fiber is the group part so you can make an idea of what I wanna do.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import "./Boxes.css";
import axios from 'axios';

const path = 'https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies/'

function GetMoon(path) {
  const [moon_data, setmoon_data] = useState('');

  useEffect(()=> {
    try {
      const fetchData = async ()=>{
        const result = await axios (path)     
        setmoon_data(result.data);
      }

      fetchData();

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al obtener datos de la API', error);
    }
  },[path])

  return moon_data;
}

const Scene = () =>{
  var moon = '';
  var moons = [];
  var complexBodies = [];
  var simpleBodies = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async() =>{
      await axios.get(path).then((response) => {
        if(response != null){
          response.data.bodies.map((body)=>{
            if (body.moons){
              complexBodies.push(body);
            }else{
              simpleBodies.push(body);
            }
          })
        }
        
      })
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])
  console.log(complexBodies);
  console.log(simpleBodies);
if(simpleBodies){
  console.log(simpleBodies)
  return(
    <>
      {simpleBodies.map((body)=>(
        console.log(body)
      ))}
      {
      complexBodies.map(body =>{
        console.log("complex map")
        moons = body.moons;
        return(<group key={body.englishName + "Group"} position={[body.perihelion/10, 0, 0]}>
          <Box key={body.englishName} name={body.englishName} position={[0, 0, 0]} size={[body.meanRadius, 100, 100]} color={'white'} />
          <>
          {moons.map((moon)=>{
            moon = GetMoon(moon.rel);
            console.log(moon)
          })}
          </>
        </group>)
      })}
    </>
  )}
  else{return(<></>)}

}
export default function Boxes() {
  return (
      <div className='Boxes'>
        <p>aaaa</p>
         <Scene />
      </div>
  )
}
```

Essentially what I need is the console.log inside the maps to show the object they are using so I can transform them into three fiber objects.

Comment: There are a variety of uses of `.map()` and `console.log` here.  Which one are you referring to specifically?  What specific problem are you observing in that one and what debugging have you done?

Comment: Neither of the maps inside the return seem to work. The moment I enter the return the simpleBodies and complexBodies arrays don't show the objects if I console.log them.

Comment: If the problem is in how the data is being mapped, can you update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) with hard-coded data and just one map/log which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: How can I import libraries in snippets? I need to import axios and React hooks to make it work.

Comment: This can help you create a React snippet: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/328193